# Is Gradle included in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, cordova, gradle

I run `cordova requirements` on an Android app created with cordova and are getting this error:

```
Gradle: not installed
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

First I would like to say that yes, I can install it manually, but why if it should be included?
So what is the issue here? Is it a lie that it should be sufficient to install Android Studio as the error message says? Do I need to install it manually also? Or do I simply need to set a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is probably included in Android Studio. At least, some of its tooling APIs must be included to provide Gradle interop.

However, Android Studion has nothing to deal with the command line commands you're running in console, like `cordova requirements`. You should probably install it and make available globally. [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io) is a good tool to manage tools in Java world.